# How to fix "HostInitializationException" in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

First I followed the instructions to get a Function Application running.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

After successfull creation of the application, I've deployed a small HTTP triggered function to Azure for testing purposes.

My function is written in python. I am using a Linux OS for pushing to Azure.
Everything looks fine.

I use this statement for publishing:
func azure functionapp publish myApp --publish-local-settings

After successfull deployment to Azure, I've tried to reach "https://myAppName.azurewebsites.net", which gives me at first a Site with Error Code 502.
After a few minutes it change its status and I get the welcome page of the Azure Functions.

If I try to reach the function directly via: https://myAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/functionName

I get an 502.. Even after waiting 30 Minutes, the function is still not running correctly..

Please let me know, if you have related useful information.

Take a look in the "Application Insights" shows some more information:

```
09:55:40 | Trace@(none)
Hosting stopping
09:55:40 | Exception | HostInitializationException@(none)
Did not find functions with language [python].
09:55:40 | Trace@(none)
A host error has occurred
09:55:40 | Trace@(none)
Creating function descriptors.
09:55:40 | Trace@(none)
Adding Function descriptor provider for language python.
09:55:40 | Trace@(none)
1 proxies loaded
```

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason for the errors you see is because of the local.settings.json file and that being published to Azure by using --publish-local-settings overriding the settings in Azure Function App.

With below files was able to host it locally and also publish it to Azure.

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{AzureWebJobsStorage}"
  }
}
```

host.json

```
{
    "version":  "2.0"
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

*init*.py

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Running the below steps in VS Code

```
func init MyFunctionProj2 (selected Python)
cd .\MyFunctionProj2\
func new (selected HTTP trigger)
func host start     

#Pick your region of choice

az functionapp create --resource-group rgname --os-type Linux --consumption-plan-location westeurope  --runtime python --name funcappname --storage-account storageaccountname

func azure functionapp publish funcappname
```

When hosted on local it works with below URL

[image]

When published to Azure Function by following above listed steps

[image]

You can get the function URL from Azure portal with in the Function

[image]

Check the Function App settings have the right connection string for storage.

[Additional documentation reference for local settings file.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file)

Hope this helps.